# create or load ontology in eclipse using owlapi

Tags: eclipse, protege, owl-api

hello everyone i write my ontology in protege and i add owlapi to my eclipse project. i want to add my own ontology to eclipse project with these codes :

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.semanticweb.owlapi.search.Searcher.annotations;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.OWLXMLDocumentFormat;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.StreamDocumentTarget;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.StringDocumentSource;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.StringDocumentTarget;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.AddAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.AddOntologyAnnotation;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAnnotation;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAnnotationProperty;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClassAssertionAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClassExpression;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataProperty;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataPropertyRangeAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataRange;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDatatype;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDatatypeDefinitionAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDatatypeRestriction;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLEntity;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLIndividual;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLLiteral;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLNamedIndividual;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectProperty;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectPropertyExpression;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyIRIMapper;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLSubClassOfAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.PrefixManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.RemoveAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.SWRLAtom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.SWRLClassAtom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.SWRLObjectPropertyAtom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.SWRLRule;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.SWRLVariable;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.profiles.OWL2DLProfile;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.profiles.OWLProfileReport;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.profiles.OWLProfileViolation;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.InferenceType;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.Node;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.NodeSet;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.OWLReasoner;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.OWLReasonerConfiguration;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.OWLReasonerFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.ReasonerProgressMonitor;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.SimpleConfiguration;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.structural.StructuralReasonerFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.AutoIRIMapper;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.DefaultPrefixManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.InferredAxiomGenerator;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.InferredOntologyGenerator;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.InferredSubClassAxiomGenerator;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLClassExpressionVisitorAdapter;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLEntityRemover;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLOntologyMerger;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLOntologyWalker;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLOntologyWalkerVisitorEx;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.PriorityCollection;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.SimpleIRIMapper;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWL2Datatype;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWLFacet;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWLRDFVocabulary;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import uk.ac.manchester.cs.owlapi.modularity.ModuleType;
import uk.ac.manchester.cs.owlapi.modularity.SyntacticLocalityModuleExtractor;
@SuppressWarnings({ "javadoc", "null" })
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OWLOntologyManager m = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        PriorityCollection<OWLOntologyIRIMapper> iriMappers = m.getIRIMappers();
        iriMappers.add(new AutoIRIMapper(new File("materializedOntologies"),
                true));
        OWLOntology o = m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(food);
        assertNotNull(o);
    }
}
```

i don't know what's wrong here, also i try to create an ontology if you have sample codes share it. i am new in protege and also owlapi. help please

Comment: Why are you using a mapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading an ontology with OWL-API:

```
    // load file
    File file = new File("Ontology.owl);

    // loading the ontology
    try {
        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLOntology localOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);

        //getting all axioms    
        Set<OWLAxiom> axSet= localOntology.getAxioms();

    } catch (OWLOntologyCreationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thank you i do this ,but the console output is not true .this is my output <A C X >
<Y X Z >
<A B C > 
and i think this is wrong

Comment: Not that is what it is supposed to look like. You need to start analysing the set and breaking it down to what you want. If you don't like to see the IRI, you can easily remove them. Look at the OWL-API website. It has examples to show you how to deal with the data. If you have further questions, post a more detailed question with what you expect to extract and why you have failed. Then we can help you better.